# Double Type to Long Type

Tags: .net, vb.net, type-conversion

I have a variable containing a double type eg, 56.3433253. I want to convert it to a long type and maintain the decimal places.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert a double to a long type and maintain the decimals in the same variable.  However, you can convert a decimal to a long by removing the decimal and storing the # values that were after the decimal in a separate variable.

```
    Dim dbl As Double = 56.3433253
    Dim lng As Long
    Dim decimals As Integer
    Dim tmp As String = String.Empty

    'Convert to string to parse for decimal place
    tmp = dbl.ToString

    If tmp.IndexOf(".") = 0 Then
        lng = CLng(dbl)
        decimals = 0
    Else
        tmp = tmp.Substring(tmp.IndexOf(".") + 1)
        decimals = tmp.Length
        lng = CLng(dbl * Math.Pow(10, decimals))
    End If

    'Convert long value back to a double
    Dim newDbl As Double = CDbl(lng / Math.Pow(10, decimals))

    MsgBox(String.Format("Long: {0}{1}Decimals: {2}{1}Original Value: {3}", {lng, vbCrLf, decimals, newDbl}))
```

Answer (score 0):

long is defined as integer, how can you have decinals. Or perhaps this:

```
lval as long = math.floor(dval)
decval as double = dval - lval
```

Comment: oh did not know long was defined as integer ty

Answer (score 0):

long with 64-bit and always a variable as double, but you will be removed the digit after the point, I suggest you use decimal.

```
   Dim number As Double = 56.3433253
    Dim number1 As decimal = number

    me.Text = number1.ToString
```

Regards.